# Unable to call procedure inside another procedure with loop using PLPGSQL

Tags: plpgsql

Trying to save data into table using procedures and loop, but unable to solve this error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE quality_save(p_1 character varying, p_2 character varying, p_3 character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying, INOUT response character varying DEFAULT '1'::character varying)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
declare 
begin
if 1=1 then
    raise notice '_Insert start';

            insert into table_A
            (
            brand,
            model,
            year
            )
            values( 
            p_1,
            p_2,
            p_3
            );
            raise notice 'insert-end';
else 
            select 'p_1,p_2 cannot be null'  into response;
        end if;
    
   exception 
    when sqlstate '23505' then
        select 'Duplicate Record'  into response;
    --when others then 
    --  select '-1' into response;
   end
   $procedure$

********************************************************************************************
   
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE auto_save(INOUT response character varying DEFAULT '1'::character varying)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
declare
response varchar(100);
f record;
 l record;
m record;
    
begin
    
    for f in select p_1,p_2,p_3 from table_dump
     loop
    call public.quality_save(
                    p_1 =>f.p_1,
                    p_2 =>f.p_2, 
                    p_3 =>f.p_3
                        )
                        ;
     
        select 1 into response;
     end loop;  
    select 1 into response;
end;$procedure$
;
```

SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: procedure parameter "response" is an output parameter but corresponding argument is not writable
Where: PL/pgSQL function auto_save(character varying) line 182 at CALL

I tried rewriting second procedure as function but still giving the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass an argument for `response`. Call the procedure like this:

```
DECLARE
   f record;
   p_response character varying;
BEGIN
   [...]
   CALL public.quality_save(
           p_1 =>f.p_1,
           p_2 =>f.p_2, 
           p_3 =>f.p_3,
           response => p_response
        );
   [...]
```